# How to fix unsupported_grant_type error in nodejs request to Reddit API

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, reddit

I am receiving an unsupported_grant_type error when making a request to Reddit to obtain an access token. I am attempting to make an app that makes API requests without user context.

I've tried moving the parameters and headers around but to no avail.

This is the code I am currently using (note that I have username = 'my client ID' and password = 'my secret key'

```
var request = require("request");

var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token',
  headers:
   { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
   'Authorization': auth,
   },
  body: 
   JSON.stringify({grant_type: 'client_credentials',
     user: username,
     password: password})
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(response,body);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I did resolve this problem to this way.

I change the header  `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`  for `Accept: 'application/json'`.
The body doesn't make it a JSON Object, I send it as a string. 
`options.body = 'grant_type=client_credentials'`

```
    const options = {};
        options.method = 'POST';
        options.headers = new Headers({
            'Accept-Language': 'en_US',
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: auth,
        });
    options.body = 'grant_type=client_credentials';
```